# How to extract TF using CountVectorizer?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, tfidfvectorizer

How can I get the term frequency(TF) of every term in the vocabulary created by `sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer` and put them into a list or a dict?

It seems that all values corresponding to keys in the vocabulary are int numbers smaller than max_features which I set manually when initializing the CountVectorizer, rather than TF——it should be a float number. Can anyone give me a help?

```
CV=CountVectorizer(ngram_range(ngram_min_file_opcode,ngram_max_file_opcode), 
                   decode_error="ignore", max_features=max_features_file_re,
                   token_pattern=r'\b\w+\b', min_df=1, max_df=1.0) 
x = CV.fit_transform(x).toarray()
```

Comment: Can you post your code here and explain your expected result ? I think you have misunderstanding regarding what tf is if you want it to return float values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are expecting float values, you may be looking for [TFIDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf). In that case, use either [sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) or [sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) followed by [sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer.html),

If you are actually only wanting TF, you can still use [TfidfVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) or [CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) followed by [TfidfTransformer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer.html), just make sure to set the `use_idf` parameter of `TfidfVectorizer`/`Transformer`to `False` and the `norm` (normalization) parameter to `'l1'` or `'l2'`. This normalizes the TF counts.

From the SKLearn documentation:

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
>>> corpus = [
...     'This is the first document.',
...     'This document is the second document.',
...     'And this is the third one.',
...     'Is this the first document?',
... ]
>>> vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
>>> X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
>>> print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
['and', 'document', 'first', 'is', 'one', 'second', 'the', 'third', 'this']
>>> print(X.toarray())  
[[0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1]
 [0 2 0 1 0 1 1 0 1]
 [1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1]
 [0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1]]
```

The row `[0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1]` corresponds to the first document. The first element corresponds to how many times `and` has occurred in the document, the second `document`, the third `first`, etc.

Comment: Does it mean that if the "use_idf" is set to "False",I can only get the TF counts rather than Tf-idf?  I knew very poor in NLP，so maybe I misunderstood the meaning of TF（x）——It  means frequency of word x  appearing in a text rather than in all the texts.Is it correct?

Comment: Correct, TF means appearing in a single document, not the entire corpus. Setting `use_idf` to `True` will introduce a whole new factor, changing TF into TFIDF.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Well what is the meaning of values in the vocabulary created by CountVectorizer?(Keys are the most common terms in the corpus.) They look like indexs. Are those terms sorted in dictionary order,which the values are ranks?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Each row in the matrix corresponds to one document, and each element in each row should be an integer. In you code, you can call `CV.get_feature_names()` to get the order of the terms in the matrix. To make it more clear, I've edited my answer to include an `sklearn` example.